# why do we need to know the name of file being processed in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I came across a post enquiring about how to get a filename being processed by mapreduce. That makes me wonder under what circumstances do we need to know the name or path of the file that is being processed.

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();

String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

Thanks
basam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

Say you need to efficiently generate unique integers based on mapper id like it is done here: [Unique Key generation in Hive/Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835062/unique-key-generation-in-hive-hadoop/27868861#27868861)

Or maybe you have an entirely different reason to use the mapper id (returned by context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID().getId())

The problem with the mapper task id is that it is not assigned deterministically based on input file.

For example, your mapper input files maybe result of a preceding reducer and say you have 10 of input partitions:

output-r-00000
output-r-00001
...
output-r-00009

Now you need to feed this data to a mapper and may need this mapper to have an id that corresponds directly to the input file index.

Normally, first thing you do in this case is disabling input split so each mapper would entirely process its own partition.

But as I said earlier mappers are not assigned deterministically so you cannot rely on context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID().getId():

Sometimes mapper 0 will process output-r-00000, sometimes output-r-00001, and so on.

So to come up with a custom mapper id deterministically you may use input file name which you can parse to get the partition index.

Comment: thanks much for detailed explanation yurgis. Is there any sample program that you can suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

There are several situation where the name of the file is important, by example:

1. The timestamp in the file name is required in the process.
2. Depending on the filename you can process the file different. Like if you have a two very similar file types that require a similar process with small differences (If not, may be it is better to have two different mapreduce jobs).
3. When in addition of the process you want to track the name of the files processed.
4. etc